# What happens when a user has used their votes to close for the day?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

What happens when a user has finished all their votes to close for a day?

Comment: is it that hard to check it?

Comment: Just a question for sake of curiosity, as I have still 40 votes and I could not find clear information.

Comment: Don't do it! You'll get eaten by a grue.

Comment: @nicael Yes, It's a bit hard if you're doing it properly, instead of blindly voting to close everything...

Comment: A warm, fuzzy feeling from helping the community. Or a warm, fuzzy logic pathway change in the roboreviewer code, depending.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dialog will still open when you hit "close", but it would be written "0 votes remaining" and once you hit "Vote to close", you'll see "Daily voting limit reached, vote again in X hours"

Comment: Ok so it is only a daily limit? I thought would be an account limit or smt else. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Gibbo on SO its 40 votes/day.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of it! I appreciate your answer!

Comment: I would propose editing the text  as "X votes remaining daily"

Comment: [It's 50 close votes per day](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), per the privilege description. @GibboK The pop-up window is not meant to teach users how close votes work, this is what the privilege page and FAQ are for.

Comment: @CareBear some time ago it was 40... now already 50. Something happenning in this world... :)

Comment: It's 40 VTC reviews, but 50 votes.